# Upload multiple files to Symfony Backend manually (without form)

Tags: reactjs, symfony, symfony4

I'm facing an issue trying to send multiples files from a ReactJS App to a Symfony Backend.

**I upload two files but only one is visible in my Symfony backend.**

Data are sent from a ReactJS dropzone, I well checked that the two files are sent via `formData`, I well used the `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` to post the data.

In Chrome Newtwork Tab, the Form Data details shows that two files are well attached to the request :

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryTif9sihCtI30UXXS Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="glacier-583419_960_720.jpg"
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryTif9sihCtI30UXXS Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image-ile.jpg" Content-Type:
> image/jpeg

Nevertheless, in my Symfony backend the File Parameter Bag only shows one file :

```
return $request->files;
```

Serialized response :

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "file": {
            "test": false,
            "original_name": "glacier-583419_960_720.jpg",
            "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
            "error": 0
        }
    },
    "file_keys": [
        "error",
        "name",
        "size",
        "tmp_name",
        "type"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, **in "parameters", only one file is present instead of two.**

Is anybody already encountered this problem ? I don't have any idea of what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue, it was trivial but it could help someone else for future readings.

As per indicated in the Form Data sent :

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryTif9sihCtI30UXXS Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="glacier-583419_960_720.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryTif9sihCtI30UXXS Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image-ile.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg

Each element added in the Form Data had the same `name` value.
Here is the problem :

```
var tempFormData = new FormData();
setFormData(acceptedFiles.map((file)=>{
   tempFormData.append('file', file);
}));
```

Corrected code :

```
var tempFormData = new FormData();
setFormData(acceptedFiles.map((file)=>{
   tempFormData.append(file.name, file);
}));
```

So the error was not coming from Symfony but from front-end App not well formatting the data sent.